# create folder in windwos8 access denied

Tags: c#, windows-8, io, windows-runtime, local-storage

I use the code below to create folder in app installed folder, but I alwasy receive access denied exception.

```
StorageFolder appFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        if (!await CheckIfFolderExist(appDataFolderName))
        {                
            StorageFolder appDataFolder = await appFolder.CreateFolderAsync(appDataFolderName);
            StorageFolder userFolder = await appDataFolder.CreateFolderAsync(userFolderName);
            StorageFolder contactFolder = await appDataFolder.CreateFolderAsync(contactFolderName);
        }
        else
        {
            StorageFolder appDataFolder = await appFolder.GetFolderAsync(appDataFolderName);
            if (!await CheckIfSubFolderExis(appDataFolderName, userFolderName))
            {
                await appDataFolder.CreateFolderAsync(userFolderName);
            }
            if (!await CheckIfSubFolderExis(appDataFolderName, contactFolderName))
            {
                await appDataFolder.CreateFolderAsync(contactFolderName);
            }
        }

 // Check if the app folder exists
    private async Task<bool> CheckIfFolderExist(string folderName )
    {
        bool folderExist = false;
        try
        {
            StorageFolder appFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            StorageFolder appDataFolder = await appFolder.GetFolderAsync(folderName);                
            folderExist = true;
            return folderExist;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            return folderExist;
        }
    }

    // Check if the app subfolder exists
    private async Task<bool> CheckIfSubFolderExis(string folderName,string subFolderName)
    {
        bool subFolderExist = false;
        try
        {
            StorageFolder appFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            StorageFolder subFolder = await appFolder.GetFolderAsync(subFolderName);
            subFolderExist = true;
            return subFolderExist;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            return subFolderExist;
        }
    }
```

Anyone has ideas?

Comment: It may be useful to tell us which line raises the exception, creation of the folder, or checking whether the folder exists?

Comment: Thanks @Lukazoid! The exception is thrown in CheckIfFolderExist method, the fifth line, GetFolderAsync.

Comment: You do not have access to that folder? Its weird you have a FileNotFoundException, can you please add a additional [DirectoryNotFoundException catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directorynotfoundexception.aspx) to confirm. I see your next comment, please still confirm with the additional catch in the `try-catch`. Cheers

Comment: But it is the folder which I installed the app, it should be accessed by default

Comment: @James You are using `appDataFolderName` in the call to `CheckIfFolderExist`, what is the value of `appDataFolderName`? I cannot see it in the code

Comment: @Lukazoid and Jeremy Thompson, sorry, my mistake, the exception isn't thrown from CheckIfFolderExist method, it is thrown from "await appFolder.CreateFolderAsync(appDataFolderName)" line

Comment: @Lukazoid, appDataFolderName is a string type which defined before

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't create a folder in your app data folder. You must use either the LocalFolder, RomaingFolder or TemporaryFolder (all found in the [ApplicationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx) class)

The reason for this is to support software upgrades etc. Why do you want to save in the appdata folder - perhaps I could suggest the best folder above to use.

Comment: Hi @Ross, thanks for your reply, I want to store some user data in xml files, every user need a xml file, so I want to create a folder, could I store the folder in Documents Libary?

Comment: No, in this case the LocalFolder is the correct place. (if it's just going to be a small file RomaingFolder would be better as it will sync with the user). All the folders I described are user specific.